# How do I keep my time updated

Tags: c#, timer

When I execute the code it gets the current time e.g 11.00 but 2 minutes later it still shows the time that I executed the program e.g 11.00 when I want it to show 11.02 .

Tried using a Timer.Tick event but for some reason it's not changing the time after a minute.

```
public string time;

public DispatcherTimer myTimer;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    SetUpClock();

    SetUpIdleTimer();
    tbkTime.Text = time;
}

void SetUpClock()
{
    // sets up new timer
    DispatcherTimer Timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    // gets today's time
    time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag));

    Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(delegate(object s, EventArgs a)
    {
        time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag));

        Timer.Stop();
        Timer.Start();
    });

    Timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
    Timer.Start();
}

void SetUpIdleTimer()
{
    myTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(myTimer_Tick);

    myTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
    myTimer.Start();
}

public void myTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myTimer.Stop();
    myTimer.Start();
}
```

Comment: Theres a few problems with your code, The one that answers your question is you only ever update the variable `time` not the `tbkTime.Text`, the second is i'm pretty sure your timer is out of scope once you've set it up (`SetUpClock`) so it won't ever really work as you expect

Comment: You should update `tbkTime.Text` instead of `time`. Also, Stop and Start in the Tick handler are redundant. Throw them away.

Comment: Thanks guys that answered my question.

Comment: Also, note that having the timer tick every minute means that it can lag for up to ~59 seconds after the clock changes. This might be confusing to the user.

Comment: To keep the clock in sync a timer needs to tick ever second, which halts your application every second. It would be better to create a background worker to display the clock so you main thread has no interruptions.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is you can create class for clock and use `Task` and `CancellationToken` in it. For example :

```
class Clock
{
    Task t;
    CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    Action<DateTime> updateFunction;

    internal Clock(Action<DateTime> updateFunction)
    {
         this.updateFunction = updateFunction;

         t = new Task(() =>
         {
             while (!source.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
             {
                 Thread.Sleep(1000);
                 updateFunction(DateTime.Now);
             }
         }, source.Token);
    }

    internal void Start()
    {
        if(t == null) return;

        t.Start();
    }

    internal void Stop()
    {
        source.Cancel();
    }
}
```

And somewhere in your code use it :

```
  Clock clock;

  void SetUpClock()
  {
      clock = new Clock(t => tbkTime.Text = t.ToString("HH:mm",
          CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));        

      clock.Start();
   }

   void StopClock()
   {
       clock.Stop();
   }
```